# Compute $f_x(0,0)$ etc. for the following function $f(x,y))$

Tags: calculus

Let
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
xy \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2} \text{ when } (x,y) \neq (0,0)  \\[2ex]
0 \text{ when } (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$

Compute $f_x(0,0)$, $f_y(0,0)$, $f_{xx}(0,0)$, $f_{xy}(0,0)$.

So, here's my problem: when I do compute $f_x$ I'm left with a function that is fraction made entirely of variables and no constants, so that $f_x$ is undefined.

What exactly am I supposed to do?

Comment: Please show us what you think is the wrong answer. And by $f_xx$ do you mean $f_{xx}$? Use `f_{xx}` for a subscript like that.

Comment: Is the numerator $x^{4} - y^{4}$?

Comment: @GFauxPas Thanks! I edited it. Sorry, I hadn't noticed.

Comment: @Mattos yes, it becomes something like that. Something decidedly, undefinable.

Comment: @Siyanda Sorry, I mean does the function $f(x,y)$ have numerator $x^{4} - y^{4}$ when $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$? I can't read it properly.

Comment: Nope, it says $x^2 + y^2$.... @mattos

Comment: You must write down the basic definition of partial derivative in terms of a quotient, and then take a limit.

Comment: @Siminore thanks! I tried that and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f_x(\mathbf{0})= \lim_{x \to 0}\left({\frac{f(x,0) - f(0,0)}{x - 0}}\right) =  \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\left({x0\dfrac{x^2 - 0^2}{x^2 + 0^2}}\right)- 0}{x-0}$$

and so on.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried that and it worked1

Comment: @Siyanda Happy to help. In the future, you should include your attempted answer in the question, even if you think it's incorrect.

Comment: I know! @gfauxpas - I usually do that. But today my mind was elsewhere

Comment: The numerator in the first difference quotient should be $f(x,0)-f(0,0).$